# decoding dynamic keys and values from JSON

Tags: json, swift4, codable

I'm trying to decode JSON where I have dynamic keys and value types.   I've tried to follow the question and answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46111863/how-to-write-a-decodable-for-a-json-in-swift-4-where-keys-are-dynamic) and can get my dynamic keys but then seem unable to get the values as well as they type is always different. I would ideally like to be able to have the 'parameters' property as a dictionary but I'm unsure how to go about this.  My code is below.

```
let jsonString = """
{
    "type": "some type",
    "message": "some message",
    "parameters": {
        "randomKey": "some value",
        "anotherKey": 99,
        "padlock": "another string",
        "fakeKey": true
        }
    }

"""

struct MyStruct : Decodable {

let type:String!
let message:String!
var parameters:DynamicParameters!

struct DynamicParameters: Decodable {

    var keys:[String]!

    private struct CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        var intValue: Int?
        var stringValue: String

        init?(intValue: Int) { self.intValue = intValue; self.stringValue = "" }
        init?(stringValue: String) { self.stringValue = stringValue }
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        self.keys = [String]()
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        for key in container.allKeys {
            self.keys.append(key.stringValue)
            }
        }
    }
}

if let jsonData = jsonString.data(using: .utf8) {
do {
    let list = try JSONDecoder().decode(MyStruct.self, from: jsonData)
    print (list)
    /// prints MyStruct(type: some type, message: some message, parameters: DynamicParameters(keys: ["anotherKey", "randomKey", "padlock", "fakeKey"]))

} catch {
    print(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess the effort to accomplish that is greater than using the traditional `JSONSerialization` way.

Comment: You are going against the design of `Codable`, which is to use strong typing and make all keys known at build time. Redefine `DynamicParameters` as a struct with optional properties, each having its own type